# How to get size of ViewPager in Android

Tags: android-viewpager

I'm trying to get the size of the `ViewPager` with this code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    app = new AppsLoader(getApplicationContext());
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    RelativeLayout relative_main= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_main);
    layoutWidth = viewPager.getWidth();
    Toast.makeText(this,String.valueOf(layoutWidth),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Result: 0

How can I get the size of the `ViewPager`?

Comment: Could you please post your xml code for the ViewPager?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the `ViewPager` width before it has been drawn, so the returned width value is always 0. This behavior happens with all the `View` objects.

What you have to do is to get that value after the `ViewPager` is drawn.

Try this inside your `onCreate()` method:

```
    int layoutWidth = viewPager.getWidth();

    viewPager.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("Check my ViewPager Width", "width " + viewPager.getMeasuredWidth());
            }
        });
```

This works because the runnable doesn't execute until the layout (and therefore, your `ViewPager`) has been drawn.

See if it helps.